# Download original Canvas even after resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j15gO.png)

Step1) I am drawing an image of 1920*1080 to canvas1 with the drawImage(image,0,0);

setp2) Now i am taking another logo image and drawing it to another canvas called canvas2 with the drawImage(logo,0,0);

I used fabricjs to for logo drag able and re sizable functionalities.

Step3) Then i am drawing canvas1 & canvas2 to another canvas called canvas3 and downloading it.

In this case everything is fine except image is displaying large(1920*1080). for user experience I have used image resize method to reduce the image and displayed in 900*500 canvas. But when i am downloding i should get the original canvas of 1920*1080 with logo. But i am getting 900*500 with logo.

Can any one help in this regards will be greatful

**The resizing code**

Here real width & real Height are width & height of background image

```
function ImageResize(){ 
    var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
    var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d'); 
    var background = document.getElementById('background'); 
    var wrh = realWidth / realHeight; 
    newWidth = d_canvas.width; 
    newHeight = newWidth / wrh; 
    if (newHeight > d_canvas.height) { 
        newHeight = d_canvas.height; 
        newWidth = newHeight * wrh; 
    } 
    context.drawImage(background,0,0, newWidth , newHeight); 
}
```

Comment: How is the downloading step implemented?

Comment: link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL(); where canvasId here is the canvas id of image with logo

Comment: How are you resizing?

Comment: Here real width & real Height are width & height of background image function ImageResize(){
var d_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = d_canvas.getContext('2d');
 var background = document.getElementById('background');
  var wrh = realWidth / realHeight;
            newWidth = d_canvas.width;
            newHeight = newWidth / wrh;
            if (newHeight > d_canvas.height) {
                newHeight = d_canvas.height;
                newWidth = newHeight * wrh;
            }
            context.drawImage(background,0,0, newWidth , newHeight);
        }

Comment: If you need detailed information please go through my website : http://cricmovie.com/bbb-imagecrop/

Answer (score 1):

Use the extended form of `drawImage` to scale and reposition the logo over the original background image:

1. Create a 3rd html5 canvas sized to 1920x1080 and draw your step1-image to the 3rd canvas.
2. Recalculate the Logo coordinates & sizes provided by FabricJS from 900x500 to 1920x1080:

   ```
   // pseudo-code
   // Given FabricJS's position & size of the logo on a 950x500 stage
   // Calc the logo's relative position & size vs a larger background
   logoX *= 1920/900;
   logoY *= 1080/500;
   logoWidth *= 1920/900;
   logoHeight *= 1080/500;
   ```
3. Draw the logo onto the 3rd canvas using the recalculated position & size

   ```
   thirdContext.drawImage(
       logoImage,
       0,0,logoImage.width,logoImage.height,
       logoX,logoY,logoWidth,logoHeight
   );
   ```
4. Export the 3rd canvas

Comment: Please go through this url : http://cricmovie.com/bbb-imagecrop/ and getstart>desktop wallpaper>1920*1080>next>proceed to add logo> save > download.. Please go through above mentioned steps i am able to download image but its taking 900*500 as image and reaming as white space this is what my problem exactly like wise i have to write code for rest of all the devices, Please suggest in this regards thanks

Comment: Or can you provide any real time example working with same concept

Comment: @Bikshus. Time does not permit a visiting cricmove.com. Steps #2 & #3 are 90% of the answer. You should be able to finish the code from here. :-)

Comment: When I am applying it is showing this error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': Valid arities are: [3, 5, 9], but 7 arguments provided.